# SSH Session Hangs When Using For-Loop

Tags: bash

I would like to SSH to a list of servers, to gather data in an automated fashion.

Right now my session begins with msg "Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal." and continues on without ever being connected to the remote servers.

If I remove '-n' form the SSH line, it connects to the remote server and stops the script execution, until the SSH session is disconnected.

```
 for host in $(cat host_list);
    do
        ssh -n -o stricthostkeychecking=no $host
        var1=$(awk -F '.' '{print $1}' some_file )
        var2=$(some_command $var1)
        echo $var2
    done
```

> > Original Post (For context if desired): 
> >     [Data Extrapolation & Bash Logic within Expect Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47516529/data-extrapolation-bash-logic-within-expect-script?noredirect=1#comment81991915_47516529)

Comment: I'm a bit confused what this script is trying to do. Do you want the commands in `$()` to be executed on the remote machine?

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Comment: forget the loop for a moment and show us what command(s) you want to run on the remote host; also tell us where `some_file` and `some_command` reside ... locally or on the remote host(s)

Comment: Everything in loop (After SSH) is to be executed and exists on the remote server. host_list is the only file aside form the script itself that will exist locally.

Comment: to solve the "Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated ..." problem, try `ssh -t -t -t -n -o ...` (yes, really, multiple `-t`s ;-) ) . Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You got a [useless use of cat award](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html#cat)

Use a `while` loop instead. Also dont forget to escape dollar sign inside the `awk` program which you want to run remotely to avoid expansion locally:-

```
while read host
do
        ssh -n -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $host "awk -F'.' '{ print \$1 }' some_file"

done < host_list
```

Answer (score -1):

It's looks like what you want is to grab info from a remote file and then do some processing.  What you'll need to do is execute the `awk` command from ssh like:

`cmd="awk -F '.' '{print $1}' some_file"
for host in $(cat host_list); do
    var1=$(ssh -o stricthostkeychecking=no $host $cmd)
    var2=$(some_command $var1)
    echo $var2
done`

Comment: Why are you putting the command in a variable? Without proper quoting or escaping, the value in `cmd` will contain *the current script's* value for `$1` rather than the literal string `$1` in the Awk script, which is probably a syntax error.  More generally, you need to review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable